# Пунктуация "затем"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Читаю самоучитель по гитаре: "Затем, в течение 3-5 дней запомните первую октаву, потом вторую", - оправдана ли запятая после слова "затем"? Если да, то почему? Не опечатка ли?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая ошибочна.

Ссылку на аналогичный вопрос я вам дал. Два слова, впрочем, добавлю. 
Авторы, отделяющие "затем" в начале фразы, видимо, вкладывают смысл, близкий к "итак", "таким образом". В этом случае запятая оправдана. Но нигде в пособиях подобное употребление "затем" не дается как нормативное. Так что максимум - авторская пунктуация.

Answer (score 0):

Нестандартное предложение, к которому можно "придраться" со многих сторон. Далее сначала отвечу на вопрос, а затем также опишу достаточно "интересные" конструкции, которые так же могли быть в предложении и, как мне кажется, придать ему более нормативный вид.

Запятая перед словом "затем" в данном контексте не требуется, если мы говорим о стандартах обособления обстоятельств. Дело в том, что если оно выражено **одиночным наречием**, то обычно не обособляется. Единственным исключением может стать авторская запятая, однако сильно сомневаюсь в этом ввиду того, что предложение взято из руководства.

Теперь возможные вариации предложения, которые я считаю более уместными:

**Затем, *в течение 3-5 дней*, запомните первую октаву, потом вторую**. Здесь я поставил вторую запятую, замыкающую уточняющий оборот.

**Затем *в течение 3-5 дней* запомните первую октаву, потом вторую**. Убрал запятую после "затем".

*Затем в течение 3-5 дней запомни**найте** первую октаву, потом вторую*. В данном случае мне показалось странным сочетание "запом**ните** в течение 3-5 дней". Можно подумать, что создатель руководства выдвигает чёткий срок, в течение которого необходимо мгновенно запомнить октаву. На мой взгляд, несовершенный вид глагола здесь более уместен, так как речь всё же идёт о процессе.

Comment: Да, уточнение нужно было обособить двумя запятыми, но по смыслу уточнение к "затем" должно бы было выражаться не длительностью, а положением во времени, не "сколько времени", а "когда именно" (напр. "с третьего по пятый день"  - начиная с того момента, тогда это было бы частным случаем от "затем").

Comment: Как знаете. У меня возникла ассоциация с временным промежутком, но Ваше мнение тоже верно.

Comment: [Весь абзац для полного понимания](https://pp.userapi.com/c854120/v854120657/6608a/JCxQ8f61PjU.jpg)